# Dar formato a la salida de datos de una solicitud HTTP en python

Tags: python, http

Soy nuevo en Python.
Tengo la siguiente solicitud en python y quisiera saber como dar formato a la salida de datos o como poder pasar esos datos a un excel, lo estoy ejecutando en la consola de windows.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/events")
print(r.url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.json())
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Dependiendo de lo que entiendas por "dar formato", algo muy sencillo que podría servirte sería `from pprint import pprint` y luego `pprint(r.json())`

Comment: Pasar los datos a un excel puede ser sencillo, o imposible, dependiendo de lo que haya en el json. Si es una simple lista de diccionarios en la que todos los diccionarios usan las mismas claves, eso se podría traducir a una tabla excel en la que cada diccionario sería una fila, y las columnas serían las claves. Pero el json puede estar muy enredado, con muchos campos anidados de diferentes tipos. En ese caso no está para nada claro cómo podrías convertir eso a una estructura bidimensional que es la tabla excel.

Comment: @abulafia muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Probe @BorjaMoreno el enlace provisto en: [Convert JSON to CSV](http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm) y se llega hasta la columna `ZO` pero en las filas se aprecia muchos vacios, es decir no se genera una estructura que pueda ser empleada por ejemplo en **tablas dinámicas**. Esto no quiere decir que no pueda lograrse, pero se tiene que tener claro cómo se va usar esa tabla en **Excel**, antes de embarcarse en tal empresa. Se tendría que hacer todo el modelado de datos en **Python** y luego emplear **openpylx** o similar para ir grabando en las filas y columnas respectivas la data.

Comment: Adicionalmente se tiene que verificar que la disposición de los datos **Json** no excedan las [Especificaciones y límites de Excel](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/especificaciones-y-l%C3%ADmites-de-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)